# Why am I getting "expected expression" when everything is closed properly with Pylance?

Tags: javascript, python, pylance

I am trying to use JavaScript inside a Python app using Js2Py lib and I keep getting an "{" was not closed (when it is) on line 34 and "expected expression" error from Pylance at line 35 for "global".

What am I missing/doing wrong?

```py
import js2py

# var_stars = js2py.eval_var('var')


    var_stars = [
        [0, 1.39734], 
        [2.6521683, 0],
        [2.5652089, 5.97229],
        [5.6232309, 2.98584],
        [2.1902414, 2.23642]
    ]
    
    # const = js2py.eval_const('const')
    # A4 = js2py.eval_A4('A4')
    # A4Width = js2py.eval_A4Width('A4Width')
    
    
    const_A4Width = 210
    const_A4Height = 297
    A4_measures = const_A4Width * const_A4Height
    const_A4Margin = 5
    
    
    setTimeout = js2py.eval_setTimeout('setTimeout')
    document = js2py.eval_document('document')
    generatePDF = js2py.eval_generatePDF('generatePDF')
    
    # const = js2py.eval_const('const')
    # console = js2py.eval_console('console')
    
    def generatePDF():  
      {
        global jsPDF 
        var doc = new jsPDF();
    
        const color = document.querySelector('select').value;
        console.log(color);
    
        
        doc.setFillColor(255, 255, 255);
        doc.setLineWidth(1);
        doc.setDrawColor(0,255,0);
        doc.circle(120, 20, 5, "S"); 
        
    
        var points = generatePoints(200, 10, A4Margin, A4Width-A4Margin-6, A4Margin, A4Height-A4Margin-6);
        for( var i=0; i<points.length; i++ )
        {
          drawEurion(points[i][0], points[i][1], Math.random()*2*Math.PI, color); 
        }
    
        
        for( var i=0; i<points.length; i++ )
        {
          console.log(points[i][0], points[i][1])
          
          for( var j=i+1; j<points.length; j++ )
          {
            var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points[i][0]-points[j][0],2)+Math.pow(points[i][1]-points[j][1],2))
            if( distance<10 )
              console.log('d', i, j, Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points[i][0]-points[j][0],2)+Math.pow(points[i][1]-points[j][1],2)) )
              
          }
      
        }
        
          
        //doc.save("eurion.pdf")
        //pdf_test_harness_init(pdf, "Open in Reader (or Firefox) to see the PDF outline");
        //doc.output('datauri') //datauri
        document.querySelector('iframe').src=doc.output('datauristring');
    
    
    
        function drawEurion(offsetX, offsetY, angle, color)
        {
          doc.setDrawColor(color);
          doc.setLineWidth(0.24834293);
          const centreX = 2.6;
          const centreY = 3;
    
          for( var i=0; i<stars.length; i++ )
          {
            var x = offsetX + centreX + Math.cos(angle)*(stars[i][0]-centreX) + Math.sin(angle)*(stars[i][1]-centreY)
            var y = offsetY + centreY - Math.sin(angle)*(stars[i][0]-centreX) + Math.cos(angle)*(stars[i][1]-centreY)
            doc.circle(x, y, 0.36089846, "S");
          }
          //doc.setDrawColor(0,255,0);
          //doc.circle(offsetX+centreX, offsetY+centreY, 4.4, "S");
          
        }
    
        function generatePoints(number, distance, minX, maxX, minY, maxY, )
        {
          var points = [];
          var tries = 0;
          while( points.length<number && tries<40 )
          {
            tries = 0;
            var validPoint = false;
            while( tries<40 && validPoint==false )
            {
              tries++;
              var x = minX + Math.random()*(maxX-minX)
              var y = minY + Math.random()*(maxY-minY)
              validPoint = true
              for( var i=0; i<points.length; i++ )
              {
                if( Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points[i][0]-x,2)+Math.pow(points[i][1]-y,2))<distance )
                //if( Math.abs(points[i][0]-x)<distance/2 || Math.abs(points[i][1]-y)<distance/2 )
                {
                  validPoint = false;
                  break;
                }
              }
              if( validPoint )
                points.push([x,y])
            }
          }
          return points
          
        }
      
    
        setTimeout(generatePDF, 10)
        document.querySelector('select').oninput = generatePDF(); 
        document.querySelector('select').onchange = generatePDF();
        document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = (setTimeout(generatePDF()), 10) 
        return False
      }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that Pylance doesn't understand Javascript syntax.

Comment: Also, I don't think you're using `js2py` correctly.  You can't mix raw javascript code with python code; the javascript "code" has to be contained in a string.